# looking for an element that contains a certain text and multiplying

Tags: jquery

For each element of my html I want it to take its text and multiply it by 10 and change its value, however this code below is not working correctly.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("p:contains(0.)").text(
        parseFloat($("p:contains(0.0)")) * 10;
      );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>0.1</p>
    <p>0.12</p>
    <p>0.001</p>
```

Comment: It looks like your script has a syntax error in the console.  That is almost always the best place to start with debugging.  In this case, I think you just have an extra semicolon at the end of the third line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[text()](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_text.asp#:%7E:text=The%20text()%20method%20sets,content%20of%20ALL%20matched%20elements.) usage:

`$(selector).text(function(index,currentcontent))`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("p:contains(0.)").text(function(i,current) {
        return parseFloat(current) * 10;
      })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>0.1</p>
    <p>0.12</p>
    <p>0.001</p>
```

Comment: `p:contains(0.)` selector will only get you the elements having number starting with `0.`